# User claims Azure active Directory in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, claims-based-identity

I've just put my website on azure and I have some trouble with user claims.

I want to create special access from user who are from a special group in my azure active directory and when I was coding my website on localhost I make it this way :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                CookieHttpOnly = true
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                        {
                            if(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "groups" && x.Value == "587642-sff4-f4c0-8085-ssdfe45d87ed"))
                            {
                                context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("roles","Admin"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("roles", "User"));
                            }

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

If the user is in the group, he get the claim "Admin" and if he is not, he get "User".

On localhost, It was working perfectly but now I putted it on Azure, it doesn't go in the "Admin" claim anymore, only giving the User claim...

Can someone explain me where the problem come from?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT** : I've made some test and it appears that the application is not finding groups or value(587642-sff4-f4c0-8085-ssdfe45d87ed) in `context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims`

Comment: MrPixel6, have you ever solved this or found a workaround? I'm facing a very similar issue where group claims are included in Identity.Claims locally, but they're missing when the application is deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log out your claims and in particular what groups are present in the claims. Otherwise: Do you have access to more than one AAD tenant? Maybe you're on the wrong tenant when you go in the cloud.

Comment: I only have one tenant ! And I made a test that shows it doesn't found any " groups " or value "587642-sff4-f4c0-8085-ssdfe45d87ed" so it goes in the else statement... The weird think is that It was working fine on local...

Comment: What are you authenticating with when executing the code? Maybe the credentials are different between environments.

Comment: With the same user from the active directory who was in the admin group exactly the same as I'm doing now